# Reference statics file in app.sass with quasar

Tags: webpack, sass, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm new here, so i'm sorry if I missed something.

My Problem is the following: 
I'm setting the background-image to a div which has a defined class.
the image is defined in the sass file.

it's working for dev if I add the static path like this:

```
.iconGrey
  background:url('/statics/icon/grey.svg')
  background-size: 18px 24px !important
  background-repeat: no-repeat
```

If I now release this to a subfolder called test the / will resolve to //myurl/statics and not //myurl/test/statics

i've tried everything I found, but quasar always give me the following error:

> This dependency was not found:
>
> - statics/icon/grey.svg in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-2-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-2-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-2-3!./node_modules/@quasar/app/lib/webpack/loader.quasar-sass-variables.js!./src/css/app.sass

I've tried:

- ~/statics/
- ~statics/
- ~@statics/

as well as adding quotes, removing quotes, using single-quotes ...

so... what did I miss?
Any Help is Appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: why are you releasing in a subfolder?

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same problem using Quasar/Cordova for an android app referencing `background-image: url("/statics/textures/texture2.png");` works in DEV. Using `background-image: url("statics/textures/texture2.png");` or `background-image: url("~statics/textures/texture2.png");` gives a compile error `This relative module was not found` or `This dependency was not found`

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem when building an Android app.

I tried the following and it works in both DEV and PROD when building and installing the APK file for Android

```
background-image: url("../statics/textures/texture2.png");
```

The same issue I have with displaying images from the statics folder.
To be able to see an image I have to use

```
<img src="../statics/icons/icon-72.png" />
```

This works for me when running the app in both DEV and PROD.

It don't see this mentioned in the [documentation](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/cli-documentation/handling-assets#Static-Assets---%2Fsrc%2Fstatics)
Either I'm doing it wrong but it still works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few solution for you:

In quasar you can use require for exemple:

Use es6 syntaxe in template ':src' can help you to execute javascript in html and generate a literal string.

img tag version:

```html
 <img :src="require('your/file/location')" />
 <img :src="`${yourRequireVariable}`" />
```

You can also use background syntaxe in Pascal Case:

```html
 <div :style="{ backgroundImage: `${yourRequireVariable}` }" ></div>
```

Comment: require is a relative path for you project you start in root directory